# How to run kitchen sink (kivymd) in 2023?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

everyone!

I have problem with how to get demos and after kitchen_sink. When I installed all needed
libraries, pillows and git I haven't this directories 'demos'.
Also, I've already watch a few video guides about this but still can't solve it (all videos are about three years old).

Links : https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/getting-started/

```
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycoKlFV3-iU
```

I want to know how to get 'demos' and 'kitchen_sink' application from this git :

https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD.git

Answer (score 2):

Kitchen Sink is a separate git repo at https://github.com/kivymd/KitchenSink . Currently it requires Kivy 2.2 but the stable version of Kivy is only up to 2.1. If I update Kivy to the current v2.2 dev release, it still gives an error when it is run.  But there is a prebuilt APK that you can install and run on the git repo page.

If you are just looking for Kivy demoes you can install the kivy_examples package with:

```
python -m pip install kivy_examples
```

If you installed it in a virtual environment, you can find the demo at:

```
share/kivy-examples/demo/showcase
```

And run it with:

```
cd share/kivy-examples/demo/showcase
python main.py
```